# MySQL - How to get one of the repeated records given a condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the next results from a query. I did this:
[image: this]

Where the user "Adriana Smith" with ID 6 is repeated because she has different contract dates, to do that I did a left join from table bo_users to  bo_users_contracts (1:m One to Many Relation). The query is below:

```
SELECT bo_users.ID, bo_users.display_name, COALESCE (bo_users_contracts.contract_start_date,'-') AS contract_start_date, COALESCE (bo_users_contracts.contract_end_date, '-') AS contract_end_date, COALESCE (bo_users_contracts.current,'-') AS current
FROM bo_users
LEFT JOIN bo_users_contracts ON bo_users.ID = bo_users_contracts.bo_users_id
LEFT JOIN bo_usermeta ON bo_users.ID = bo_usermeta.user_id
WHERE (bo_usermeta.meta_key = 'role' AND bo_usermeta.meta_value = 'member')
```

But I want to get all users, but from user Adriana I just want to get the occurrence where "current" column = 1.

So the final result would be the 3 user's records:
Alejandro, Rhonda and Adriana (with "current" = 1)

Thank you!

Comment: Just put the limit on the join `LEFT JOIN bo_users_contracts ON bo_users.ID = bo_users_contracts.bo_users_id AND bo_users_contracts.current = 1`  Putting the limit in the where clause negates the left joins. (making them behave like an inner unless you handle the nulls correctly).  Typically in this case you want the limit to be applied before the joins so the left joins still functions as desired; so just add the limit to the join itself  so you don't end up excluding Poor ole Rhonda.

Comment: No, doesn't work. bo_users_contracts.current is numeric but it repeats me Aleandro user a lot of times. I want to obtain the following result: Alejandro and Rhonda same records as image but Adriana record where current = 1

Comment: If you're current query only returns 4 records. this should work.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you xQbert, I put the limit in the left join and It works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to limit on a table being outer joined, the limit should be placed on the join itself so the all records from bo_users is retained. (as indicated desired by the outer join)

Essentially the limit is applied before the join so the unmatched records from BO_users to bo_users_contracts are kept.  If applied after the join in a where clause the records from BO_user without a matching record would have a null value for current and thus be excluded when the current=1 filter is applied.

In this example the only values which should be in the where would be from table BO_USERS.

I'd even move the bo_usermeta filters to the join or you may lose bo_users; or the left join on the 3rd table should be an inner join.

```
SELECT bo_users.ID
     , bo_users.display_name
     , COALESCE (bo_users_contracts.contract_start_date,'-') AS contract_start_date
     , COALESCE (bo_users_contracts.contract_end_date, '-') AS contract_end_date
     , COALESCE (bo_users_contracts.current,'-') AS current
FROM bo_users
LEFT JOIN bo_users_contracts 
  ON bo_users.ID = bo_users_contracts.bo_users_id
 and bo_users_contracts.current = 1
LEFT JOIN bo_usermeta                     --This is suspect   
  ON bo_users.ID = bo_usermeta.user_id
WHERE (bo_usermeta.meta_key = 'role'      --this is suspect
  AND bo_usermeta.meta_value = 'member')  --this is suspect
```

The lines reading this is suspect are that way because you have a left join which means you want all users from bo_users..  However if a user doesn't have a meta_key or meta_value defined, they would be eliminated.  Either change the join to an inner join or move the where clause limits to the join.  I indicate this as you're query is "inconsistent" in it's definition leading to ambiguity when later maintained.